# How to implement structured logging when using NLog in wrapper class

Tags: asp.net, nlog, structured-logging

I am having trouble figuring out how I can use the structured logging, when NLog is in a wrapper class. I have an asp.net webapp that calls my nlog wrapper class.

It works fine for regular logging ex. `logger.Info("Gets to here.")` but i can't get it to work for structured logging calls ex. `logger.Info("This is structured logging entry @{param1}", new {Status = "processing"})`

This is my Wrapper class for NLog(EventLog.LogManager):

```
    public static void Info(params object[] args)
    {
        private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();            
        Logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, args);

        //This is what I've tried to no avail.
        //var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        //LogEventInfo le = LogEventInfo.Create(LogLevel.Info, Logger.Name, ci, args);
        //le.Parameters = args;
        //string test = le.FormattedMessage;
        //string test1 = string.Format(le.Parameters[0].ToString(), le.Parameters[1].ToString());
        //Logger.Log(typeof(LogManager), le);  
    }
```

This is my asp.net application that calls the above method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        EventLog.LogManager.Info("Test @{param1}", new { OrderId = 2, Status = "Processing" });
        return View();
    }
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing into this:

```
namespace EventLog
{
    public static class LogManager
    {
        private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public static void Info(string message, params object[] args)
        {
           Logger.Info(message, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy cow! I didn't know that params object[] will take in the rest of the arguments. Thank you sir. You saved the day! And taught me something new

Comment: @made_it_ma Welcome to the DotNet-world :)